# In Powershell, Invoke-expression is not working when entering space in the path

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I have a query like when I try to execute the expression which contains a path with space, I am getting an error as below.

Code:

```
$path="E:\Test\My space\Log"
Invoke-Expression $path 

E:\Test\My: The term 'E:\test\My' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ E:\Test\My space\Log
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (E:\Test\My :String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Could you please help me to fix this issue.?

Comment: That's the equivalent of just entering `E:\Test\My space\Log` into the console and hitting enter - what did you expect was going to happen?

Comment: Any path will have to be put into quotes so the above would look like `Invoke-expression "$path"`

Comment: You don't need `Invoke-Expression`. `& $path` will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your input Friends. I will check it out. Regret for the delayed reply.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50023419

Answer (score 4):

Use single quotes and a backtick ([grave accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent)) to escape the space:

```
$path='E:\Test\My` space\Log'
Invoke-Expression $path
```

Or programmed:

```
$path="E:\Test\My space\Log"
Invoke-Expression ($path -Replace ' ', '` ')
```

Comment: This doesn't address the problem which is a fundamental understanding issue

Comment: You are right, there is probably a fundamental understanding issue here but it does answer the question: *"Could you please help me to fix this issue.?"*

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just call

```
& $path
```

I think `Invoke-Expression` basically just types your value into the shell at face value.