# Why does invoke operator (&) and Invoke-Expression produce different results for the same input?

Tags: windows, powershell

From my understanding, the invoke operator (&) and the Invoke-Expression cmdlet should behave similar. However, as can be seen below, this is not the case:

```
PS C:\Users\admin> powershell -Command "& {""([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String('ZWNobyAnaGVsb
G93b3JsZCc=')))""}"
echo 'helloworld'

PS C:\Users\admin> powershell -Command "IEX ""([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String('ZWNobyAnaGVs
bG93b3JsZCc=')))"""
helloworld
```

Here, `'ZWNobyAnaGVsbG93b3JsZCc='` is the Base64 encoded string `"echo helloworld"`.

Can someone clarify?

Comment: Because you don't supply the same input - the `IEX` arg is not wrapped in an outer scriptblock (`{}`), so it goes one step further and actually *executes* "echo helloworld" after the parser is done expanding the string

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - Will you show how the IEX example is evaluated (each step)? What executes "echo helloworld"?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression) (whose built-in alias is `iex`) and [`&`, the call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators), serve different purposes:

- **`Invoke-Expression` evaluates a given string *as PowerShell source code***, as if you had executed the string's *content* directly as a command.

  - As such, it is similar to `eval` in `bash` and therefore **only to be used with *input that is fully under the caller's control* or input that the caller *implicitly trusts***.
  - There are often better solutions available, so [Invoke-Expression should generally be *avoided*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/)
- **`&` is used to *invoke a command* (`& <nameOrPath> [...]`) or a *script block* (`& { ... } [...]`)**:

  - Neither case involves evaluating a string *as source code*.

---

In the case at hand:

The core of your command is the following expression, which returns the *string*
`"echo 'helloworld'"` (its content doesn't include the enclosing `"` - this is simply the representation of the resulting string as a PowerShell string literal):

```bash
[Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String('ZWNobyAnaGVsbG93b3JsZCc='))
```

Also note that, due to how the command line is parsed, the `""...""` surrounding the core expression in your original commands are effectively *ignored*, which explains why the expression is *executed* rather than being treated as the content of a string.<sup>[1]</sup>

Therefore, your two commands amount to:

- `& { "echo 'helloworld'" }`

  - `&` executes the statement inside the script block, which happens to be a *string*, and a string by itself - if it isn't assigned to a variable or redirected elsewhere - is simply *output* as-is.
    In this case, the command is effectively the same as just executing `"echo 'helloworld'"` by itself (*including* the enclosing `"`, which you can think of as
    `echo "echo 'helloworld'"`), so `echo 'helloworld'` prints to the console.
  - Note that `echo` is a built-in alias for the `Write-Output` cmdlet, whose *explicit* use is rarely necessary: Return values from commands or expressions are *implicitly* output, if they are not captured in some form, as in this case,  where executing a string by itself as a statement simply outputs the string. (You can try this by submitting just `'hi'` at the prompt, for instance).
- `iex "echo 'helloworld'"`

  - This makes `iex` (`Invoke-Expression`) evaluate the string's content as source code, which therefore executes `echo 'helloworld'`, which prints `helloworld` to the console.

---

#### [1] Optional reading: PowerShell quoting woes when calling external programs

Note:

- Handling of quoting with respect to external programs or when calling from an external programs is not part of the official documentation, as far as I can tell (as of this writing, neither [about_Parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing) nor [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules) nor [about_Special_Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters) mentions it - I've opened [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/2361) to address that).
- There are flaws in the existing handling, but they cannot be fixed without breaking backward compatibility.
- When calling from PowerShell, the best approach is to use a *script block*, which bypasses the quoting problems - see below.

Even though you correctly embedded `"` by escaping them as `""` inside the overall `"..."` string from a PowerShell-*internal* perspective, ***additional escaping of `"` with `\` is needed* in order to pass them through to an *external program***, even if that external program is another instance of PowerShell called via `powershell.exe`.

- **Update**: This problem is **mostly fixed** in **v7.3+** of [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), with **selective exceptions on Windows** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74440425/45375).

Take this simplified example:

```bash
powershell.exe -command " ""hi"" "  # !! BROKEN
powershell.exe -command ' "hi" '    # !! BROKEN
```

- PowerShell-internally, `" ""hi"" "` and `' "hi" '` evaluate to a string with literal contents  `"hi"` , which, when executed, prints `hi`.
- Regrettably, PowerShell passes this string to `powershell.exe` as `" "hi" "` - note how the `""` turned into plain `"` and the enclosing *single* quotes were replaced with *double* quotes - which effectively results in  `hi`  after parsing by the new instance (because `" "hi" "` is parsed as the *concatenation* of substrings `" "`, `hi`, and `" "`), so PowerShell ends up trying to execute a (presumably nonexistent) *command* named `hi`.

By contrast, if you manage to pass the embedded as `"` as `\"` (sic) - *after* meeting PowerShell's own escaping needs - the command works as intended.
Therefore, as stated, **you need to *combine* PowerShell-internal escaping with for-the-CLI escaping in order to pass an embedded `"`**, so that:

- inside overall `"..."`, each embedded `"` must be escaped as `\""` (sic) or `` \`" `` (sic)
- inside overall `'...'`, `\"` can be used as-is.

```bash
powershell.exe -command " \""hi\"" " # OK
powershell.exe -command " \`"hi\`" " # OK
powershell.exe -command ' \"hi\" '   # OK
```

**Alternatively, use a *script block* instead of a command *string***, which bypasses the quoting headaches:

```bash
powershell.exe -command { "hi" } # OK, but only works when calling from PS
```

Note that the script-block technique **only works when calling *from PowerShell***, not from `cmd.exe`.

---

**`cmd.exe` has its own quoting requirements:**
Notably, `cmd.exe` only supports `""` for embedding double quotes (not also `` `" ``); thus, among the solutions above, only
`powershell.exe -command " \""hi\"" "` works from `cmd.exe` (a batch file) without additional escaping.

The down-side of `\""`, however, is that runs of interior whitespace between `\""...\""` are collapsed to a single space each. To avoid that, use `\"...\"`, but `cmd.exe` then sees substrings between the `\"` instances as *unquoted*, which would cause the command to break if that substring contained metacharacters such as `|` or `&`; e.g., `powershell.exe -command " \"a|b\" "`; to fix that you must individually `^`-escape the following characters: `& | < > ^`

`powershell.exe -command ' "hi" '` is similarly brittle, because `cmd.exe` doesn't recognize `'` as a string delimiter, so any metacharacters outside embedded `"..."` are again interpreted by `cmd.exe` itself; e.g., `powershell.exe -command ' "hi" | Measure-Object '`

Finally, using just `""` from `cmd.exe` for embedding `"` *sometimes* works, but not *reliably*; e.g., `powershell.exe -command " 'Nat ""King"" Cole' "` prints `Nat "King Cole` (the closing `"` is missing).
This appears to have been fixed in PowerShell *Core*.

Comment: Thank you for an excellent answer. I'm very interested in what you wrote: `"Also note that, due to how the command line is parsed, the ""..."" surrounding the core expression in your original commands are effectively ignored..."`. Can you provide a link to documentation? I've read that `""` means a single `"` when used inside `"..."`. Therefore, I'd expect that the core-expression is quoted, i.e., seen as a string.

Comment: @user111854 *I've read that `""` means a single `"` when used inside `"..."`.* That is true. But then you pass that string to `PowerShell.exe` by command line. And command line parser treat `"` as special character, thus it need to be escaped to be literal part of command.

Comment: @user111854: PetSerAl is correct, but please see my update for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Last question, why use `\""` and not `\"\"`? The \ only escapes the first `"`, so the second still has special meaning?

Comment: @user111854: The `""` is required for _PowerShell_ to recognize an `"` embedded in `"..."`, whereas the `\ ` - which has _no_ special meaning to PowerShell internally - is required for _command-line_ construction. After PowerShell's internal parsing, it is `\"` (_one_ `"` only) that  `powershell.exe` sees on its command line. By contrast, `\"\"` would cause a syntax error, because by PowerShell rules the `"` chars. aren't escaped.

Comment: @mklement0 - But, you say that PowerShell parses `\"` as `"` for command-line construction? Then `\"\"` would be parsed as `""`, which is exactly what we want? Or do you mean that `\""` is parsed as `\"`, which is equivalent to `""` when constructing a command-line, i.e., `powershell.exe -C "\""...\"""` is executed as `powershell.exe -C """..."""` (if that worked properly)?

Comment: @user111854: Yes, `\""` ends up as `\"` when `powershell.exe` sees it on its command line, and only on the command line does it expect that form of escaping. Yes, it is the equivalent of `powershell.exe -C """..."""` _if_ that worked; it actually _mostly_ works when you call _from `cmd.exe`_, but not in _all_ cases. I've also revised the answer a bit.