# batch file command to powershell command

Tags: java, powershell, batch-file, jar, start-process

I have a following batch(.bat file) command which is working great. However, i need to convert it into powershell command and need to run it through powershell. I have went through different ways that i have found online but none of them seems to work the way i want it to.

**Batch command:**

```
java -jar xyz.jar -url https://xyz.abc.com -user xyz123 -passwordHash abchgfqwfjhd1232bfyevt7676 -clientId GFGFhjxgsVGGF -clientSecret GFhjdhjdhdGGGbfsilwueibJGBjg -input C:\abc\Newfolder\xyz\  -v >> %logfile%
```

Till now i have just been able to run this basic powershell command. can someone please assist?

**Powershell command:**

```
Start-Process -FilePath https://xyz.abc.com
```

Comment: Use the command _nearly as is_  changing  `java -jar …` to `java.exe -jar …` and `%logfile%` to `$logfile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

```
 $logFile = "C:\temp\logFile.txt"
 Invoke-Expression "java -jar xyz.jar -url https://xyz.abc.com -user xyz123 -passwordHash abchgfqwfjhd1232bfyevt7676 -clientId GFGFhjxgsVGGF -clientSecret GFhjdhjdhdGGGbfsilwueibJGBjg -input C:\abc\Newfolder\xyz\  -v " | Out-File $logFile
```

`Invoke-Expression` [docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-6), be aware that `Invoke-Expression` should only be used if the string you're invoking is under your control. Another alternative is the `&` (call-operator), check this stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50018274/why-does-invoke-operator-and-invoke-expression-produce-different-results-for), which explains the differences between them.

Hope that helps.